# Creating virtual environments for python 2.7 and python 3.4 on same windows 7 pc

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, virtualenv, windows-7-x64

I am using windows 7. I have installed both python 2.7 and python 3.4 on my pc. And I have also added `C:\Python27\;C:\Python27\Scripts\;C:\Python34\;C:\Python34\Scripts\;` in the **PATH**. When I enter `python --version` in cmd it outputs `Python 3.4.4`. Now, I want to create virtual env for both 2.7 & 3.4. If I am right, I have to install `virtualenv` for python 2.7 but not for 3.4 because it already has. Please explain how should I install & create virtualenv for both.

Comment: If you scroll down that duplicate you will find a Windows solution as well.

Comment: ok, but how will i install virtualenv for 2.7

Comment: Everything is in that dupe target. Read through it. You have to specify the exact path of the Python version you want to use. From the duplicate target, look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6892302/1832539) answer.

Comment: I did it and got the error `'virtualenv' is not recognized a
operable program or batch file.`

Comment: From your question: "If I am right, I have to install virtualenv". Did you do that yet? You might want to start there.

Comment: No I haven't. that's the problem i am facing. How to do that?

Comment: @martinho have you tried [google](https://www.google.com/webhp?hl=en#hl=en&q=how+to+install+virtualenv+on+windows)? or maybe [how to install virtualenv on multiple versions of python](https://www.google.ca/webhp?hl=en#hl=en&q=how+to+install+virtualenv+on+multiple+versions+of+python)

Comment: I have tried but not getting satisfactory answer. help would be great.